# Error (sqlca.sqlcode == ECPG_DUPLICATE_KEY) Handling In Ecpg PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql, ecpg

Need to handle a error while inserting records into table (Ecpg PostgreSQL), but job should not abort/commit/rollback if any duplicate record (Primary Key).Job should skip and continue for next.

```
Note:SQL_CODE = sqlca.sqlcode

if ( SQL_CODE == -403 )  Other Way (sqlca.sqlcode == ECPG_DUPLICATE_KEY)
{
   Log_error_tab();
}   
else if ( SQL_CODE != SQL_SUCCESS )
{
   Job_fail();
}
```

If i will handle as above its handling the error by calling function **Log_error_tab()**,but its failing in next DML operation with error **"sqlerrm.sqlerrmc: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block on line  (sqlstate: 25P02)"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way PostgreSQL works: if a statement inside a transaction fails, the transaction is aborted, and all subsequent statements will fail with that message.

So you should `EXEC SQL ROLLBACK` before you attempt your next SQL statement.

If you don't want to rollback the whole transaction, you can set a savepoint prior to executing the “dangerous” SQL statement:

```
SAVEPOINT sname
```

Then, when the critical part is over, you can release the savepoint:

```
RELEASE SAVEPOINT sname
```

If you hit an error, you can roll back everything since the savepoint was set, including the error, with

```
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT sname
```

Note that you should use savepoints sparingly if you want decent performance.